# Android Animation bug

Tags: java, android

So, When I click on it it will go do the first animation which is sliding the right alittle bit and staying there and then it will AUTO do the second animation and slide back

This is how its SUPPOSED TO GO

You click on it and it will slide to the right. And when you click on it again it will slide BACK to the left.

My code:

```
     public void sideBar()
   {



       ImageView sidebar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sidebar);

       if(out == 0)
       {
       mSlideInRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
       mSlideInRight.setFillAfter(true);
       sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInRight);
       out= 1;
       }

       if(out == 1)
       {
               mSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
               sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInLeft);
               out=0;
       }

   }
```

This part is where it handles when you click on it

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {


            case R.id.sidebar:
                sideBar();
            break;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
if (out == 1)
```

condition to

```
else if (out == 1)
```

In it's current form, the code will execute the second block after finishing the first. After all, you just explicitly set `out = 1`.

Comment: Okay it worked! but on the FIRST click it will do my problem and then after that it's perfect! How can I fix the first click problem

Comment: Please edit your question and include the updated code. It might also help to know how `out` is initialized.

Comment: Fixed it! I changed int out = 1 to = 0